# Tag field needs a clear function

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, android-app

In the Android app when searching for and entering tags on a post, it is somewhat cumbersome that after selecting a tag you must then either manually select and delete or backspace over the search text to add another.

A simple X to clear the search field in preparation for finding another tag to add would add a lot to usability.

Comment: I can already vision the feature request asking to remove it due to misclicks.

Comment: @Shadow Missclicks? This is a standard interface paradigm and the wort possible misuse clears the search field. This is not for tags it's for search. Have you used the interface in question? It's really cumbersome to add a second tag.

Comment: Oops, thought you meant the X would clear all tags. Used to the iOS app which auto-select the search term so single backspace clears it up. +1, and maybe better make it clear you mean the search field? (might to trivial to some, but as you see, not all :))

Comment: I'd like it to automatically clear the box after selecting a tag from the list of suggestions. I'm lazy. A button would be good in case you put in a long tag and realized it was the wrong one, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in 1.0.84.

Mirroring the functionality of the iOS app, the tag field will now:

- have a clear button available for quickly wiping out the text.
- select all the text in the search field when you add a tag, so you can just start searching without even tapping the clear button.