# "Clear" button for tags field

Tags: feature-request, tags

I think the tags field would benefit by a "Clear" button.

I inadvertently pasted three sentences into the select tags field, thereby creating dozens of tags.  Had to click the delete 'x' one at a time to get rid of them.

Alternatives: an "Undo" button, or the ability to select all by mouse-drag and then "Cut"

Comment: At least on a Windows desktop Ctrl-A, then Delete or Backspace works to clear the entire tags field. Once you click Ctrl-A, the tags are changed back to just text, so a subset can then be selected and deleted.

Comment: I'm thinking I tried that on my Mac.  I'll have to try again on a test post.  If it works, that's good.  Still, a button clearly labeled "Undo" or "Clear" might be a good thing.

Comment: As a more cross-system alternative, you can also hold backspace. A backspace when you don't have any characters for a new tag will convert the previous tag back to text. So you can just hold down the key to delete them all without manually clicking over and over.

Comment: Worth to mention, the apps (both) [had this feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245888/tag-field-needs-a-clear-function).

Comment: I know of two tag fields (maybe there are more), after "Ask Question" and from the "filter" button after displaying the Questions search list. Which one are you referring to? The first one has a limit of 5 tags but lets you paste in dozens of them creating nonsense tags. Why would the interface let you enter more than six tags here?

Comment: @PeterJames pretty sure OP means the question's tag field, otherwise they would have mentioned it's for the custom filters. As for why it allows many tags it's a valid question and worthy of a new, separate, feature request asking to let us put only five.

Comment: @Makyen's suggestion works in an interesting way on macOS/Firefox  - Cmd-A selects everything in a "tag box" (not sure what to call it - the plain text surrounded by a border that you get when editing a tag), but doesn't change other tags. Ctrl-A changed _all_ tags to a combined single "tag box", and then I could Cmd-A and delete everything.

Comment: "I inadvertently pasted three sentences into the select tags field, thereby creating dozens of tags." - it seems to me like *guarding against this* would be a better feature.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel but allowing paste is important, and so is having a space cause separate tag. The only way would be to limit the tags to five. No?